# Why sbt updateClassifier fails to download org.scala-sbt#precompiled?

Tags: sbt

Try this in a unix shell:

```
git clone git@github.com:jsuereth/sbt-in-action-examples.git
cd sbt-in-action-examples/chapter11/scalastyle-plugin/
sbt updateClassifiers
```

With sbt 0.13.7, I get this:

```
[warn]  [FAILED     ] org.scala-sbt#precompiled-2_8_2;0.13.7!precompiled-2_8_2.jar:  (0ms)
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/precompiled-2_8_2/0.13.7/jars/precompiled-2_8_2.jar
…
[warn]  [FAILED     ] org.scala-sbt#precompiled-2_9_2;0.13.7!precompiled-2_9_2.jar:  (0ms)
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/precompiled-2_9_2/0.13.7/jars/precompiled-2_9_2.jar
…
[warn]  [FAILED     ] org.scala-sbt#precompiled-2_9_3;0.13.7!precompiled-2_9_3.jar:  (0ms)
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn]   https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/precompiled-2_9_3/0.13.7/jars/precompiled-2_9_3.jar
… 
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::
[warn]  :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.scala-sbt#precompiled-2_8_2;0.13.7!precompiled-2_8_2.jar
[warn]  :: org.scala-sbt#precompiled-2_9_2;0.13.7!precompiled-2_9_2.jar
[warn]  :: org.scala-sbt#precompiled-2_9_3;0.13.7!precompiled-2_9_3.jar
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[success] Total time: 4 s, completed Apr 13, 2015 9:51:15 AM
```

Are these warnings normal?

I noticed that the URLs that SBT is trying to look for these artifacts do not match the URLs of the artifacts published.

That is, sbt is looking for these artifacts:

https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/precompiled-2_8_2/0.13.7/jars/precompiled-2_8_2.jar
https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/precompiled-2_9_2/0.13.7/jars/precompiled-2_9_2.jar
https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/precompiled-2_9_3/0.13.7/jars/precompiled-2_9_3.jar

But in fact, the artifacts available are these:

https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/precompiled-2_8_2/0.13.7/jars/compiler-interface-bin.jar
https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/precompiled-2_9_2/0.13.7/jars/compiler-interface-bin.jar
https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/precompiled-2_9_3/0.13.7/jars/compiler-interface-bin.jar

It seems that the above "compiler-interface-bin.jar" artifacts correspond to the "sources" artifacts here:

https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/precompiled-2_8_2/0.13.7/srcs/precompiled-2_8_2-sources.jar
https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/precompiled-2_9_2/0.13.7/srcs/precompiled-2_9_2-sources.jar
https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.scala-sbt/precompiled-2_9_3/0.13.7/srcs/precompiled-2_9_3-sources.jar

- Nicolas.

Comment: this looks like it may be either a corrupted cache issue, or a http proxy issue.  Are any of those in place?

Comment: Did you find a resolution to this?

Comment: No, I haven't found a resolution to this; however, these happen much more rarely now.

Comment: Happened to me when I first checkout the project in eclipse and then switched to intellij

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that these were cause by the instability of either https://repo.typesafe.com/ (redirection proxy) or Bintray. I don't think they are normal.

For what it's worth, I was able to run `updateClassifiers` fine.